# Oracle Express edtion 11g

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, instantclient

I am getting this error when I am trying to run SQLPLUS using cmd.
I followed the instruction given on the link below to download, install and setup sqlplus instantclient :-
https://thegeekuday.wordpress.com/2013/09/12/how-to-install-oracle-11g-database-and-setup-instant-sqlplus-client/

ERROR MESSAGE :-

> The procedure entry point OCIBindByNAME2 could not be loacted in the dynamic link library C:\oracleexe\instantclient_12_1\sqlplus.exe

Please some help me!
Thanks

Comment: Did you *only* download the SQL\*Plus package, or also the required basic package? The blog you linked to doesn't make that clear, but the instructions on [the download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html) do. (What has this got to do with XE specifically, or 11g; never mind Wordpress?)

Comment: I downloaded only the SQL*PUS instantclient as metioned on the blog. Do I have to download the basic package too? If you could provide me a link on how to go about installing sqlplus then it would be helpful. :) 
Thanks @Alex Poole

Comment: The instructions are on the download page I already linked to. Step one says: "All installations REQUIRE the Basic package.".

Answer (score 1):

The instructions for installing instant client are at the bottom of the [download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html):

> **Installation Steps:**
>
> 1. Download the appropriate Instant Client packages for your platform. All installations REQUIRE the Basic package.
> 2. Unzip the packages into a single directory such as "instantclient".
> 3. Set the library loading path in your environment to the directory in Step 2 ("instantclient"). On many UNIX platforms, LD_LIBRARY_PATH is the appropriate environment variable. On Windows, PATH should be used.
> 4. Start your application and enjoy.

You have only downloaded the [SQL*Plus package](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html), which is described as "Additional libraries and executable ...". The word *additional* is important.

You have to download at least the [basic package](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html) (or [basic-lite](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html) which has less internationalisation support) to be able to use any instant client features.

All of the packages you download have to be unzipped into the same directory. You can then put that combined directory anywhere you want, and point your PATH environment variable to it.

There is more information about Instant Client [on Oracle's website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/). That is generally a better place to start than a third-party blog.

Comment: Thanks @Alex Poole for the answer!